# less --global-var seems not working

Tags: less, global-variables

I'm using less in a JEE project. Compiling less files is via an ant script.
I want to generate multiple versions of bootstrap (and some others less files) with a different color scheme.

So, my script have some :

```
<antcall target="lessfile">
    <param name="file.name.less" value="bootstrap.less" />
    <param name="file.name.css" value="bootstrap-orange.css" />
    <param name="brand-primary" value="#F44336" />
</antcall>
```

At the end of the script, I launch compilation via the line:

```
<arg line="-x ${file.name.less} ${dir.css}/${file.name.css} --global-var='my-background=${brand-primary}'" />
```

This command line itself poses no worries. The problem is to retrieve the value of 'my-background'.
In the bootstrap file, I do a simple test:

```
.test {
    color : @my-background;
}
```

And the compilation fails, stating that he does not know the @my-background variable ("variable @ my-background is undefined"), as if the argument specifying the global variable was ignored.
Can you explain to me how I can get my global variable value?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

(PS : i have lessc 1.4.2 )

Comment: Hmm, I can't test it right now, but at quick glance `lessc` command line pattern is: `lessc [option option=parameter ...] <source> [destination]` (so anything after `dst` may be simply ignored). Also note the current Less version is `2.5.3` (obviously the documentation reflects current state and not some three years old version. Though AFAIR `--global-var` option was already available in `1.4.2`).